# How do you write an iOS app that can upload data, and can then be viewed by other people with the same app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've made a few basic iOS apps, mostly just games with cocos2d though. I was wondering how one would go about writing an iOS app with which data could be uploaded from the app, and then seen by others with the same app? Would you need to set up a server to upload the data to, and if so, how would the app send and retrieve data to and from the server?
Thanks

Comment: This question is far too broad for SO's targeted question/answer model. There are plenty of tutorials available online and in books for how to write an app that shares data with other apps using a variety of mechanisms. I suggest using google or your favorite search engine to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need a server and a database structure to hold the data you are uploading to and downloading from the server. One common way to do this is with a mixture of php and MySQL. You can then use something like Json to send commands to and get data from the server from inside your app code.

Here's a tutorial that explains the basics:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app